# Validate input from SQL injection objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-injection

I'm looking for code for iOS app that can perform integrity of user input and especially validate input from SQL injection on objective c.

Answer (score 2):

Using bind variables for user-generated input will avoid any SQL injection.  If however you create the SQL statement using `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` then you will always be susceptible to such attacks.

Here's an example of using a bind variable, taken from [here](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-SDK-Database-Insert-Update-Delete-with-SQLite-and-Objective-C-C-How-To):

```
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO data(coltext, colint, coldouble) VALUES(?,?,?)";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, 1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [txt UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, integer);
sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, dbl);
sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

There are many, many examples out there.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection can be prevented if you use an input validation technique in which user input is authenticated against a set of defined rules for length, type, and syntax and also against business rules.
    Properly handle user input data, for example, remove special characters.
    By using strongly typed parameterized query APIs with placeholder substitution markers.

For more details check out this [How to prevent SQL Injection in iOS apps](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-ios-apps/2/)